# Stocks application using Web Api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I was given task to build a client server application, using any technology I want.
The task was to build a database(doesn't have to be a real database, it can be mocked). the client side should support more than one user/

I didn't use a real database I just created some shares and created a mechanism to update them from time to time using a random value.

I initialized the database with 2 users, I don't need to add users or delete them, just show I can support more than one.

Since I have a background in C# and WPF, I created 3 projects:
1. WPF/MVVM client side
2. common library
3. WebAPI - server side, which "includes" the database.

I would like you to please comment about the correctness of my implementation as if it was a code review for your team.
OOP design, usage of client server, please don't take into account I did it with WPF.
Assume you have half a day to work on the project and then submit.

I would appreciate any comments or questions.

**1. WPF project/ MVVM - I used mvvm light tool kit**

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="Client.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="enter use name: " MinWidth="75"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" MinWidth="75" Text="{Binding UserName,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Content="Get All Shares" Command="{Binding GetAllSharesCommand,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Content="Get My Shares" Command="{Binding GetSharePerUserCommand,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        <DataGrid Grid.Row="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Shares}">

        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**HttpHandler.cs**

```
namespace Client
{
    public class HttpHandler
    {
        private HttpClient client;
        public HttpHandler()
        {
            client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:18702/");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        }

        public async Task<IEnumerable<Share>> GetallSharesAsync(string path)
        {
            IEnumerable<Share> shares = null;
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(path);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                shares = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<Share>>();
            }
            return shares;
        }

        public async Task<IEnumerable<Share>> GetSharePerUserAsync(string path)
        {
            IEnumerable<Share> shares = null;
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(path);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                shares = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<Share>>();
            }
            return shares;
        }

        public async Task<IDictionary<string, int>> GetAllUsersAsync(string path)
        {
            IDictionary<string, int> users2Id = null;
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(path);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                users2Id = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IDictionary<string, int>>();
            }
            return users2Id;
        }
    }
}
```

**ClientViewModel.cs**

```
namespace Client
{
    public class ClientViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private ObservableCollection<Share> _shares;
        public ObservableCollection<Share> Shares
        {
            get { return _shares; }
            set { _shares = value; }
        }

        private string _userName;
        public string UserName
        {
            get { return _userName; }
            set
            {
                _userName = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("UserName");
                GetAllSharesCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
            }
        }
        private RelayCommand _getAllSharesCommand;
        public RelayCommand GetAllSharesCommand
        {
            get { return _getAllSharesCommand; }
            set
            {
                _getAllSharesCommand = value;
            }
        }
        private RelayCommand _GetSharesPerUserCommand;

        public RelayCommand GetSharePerUserCommand
        {
            get { return _GetSharesPerUserCommand; }
            set { _GetSharesPerUserCommand = value; }
        }

        private HttpHandler handler;
        private Dictionary<string, int> _userName2Id;
        public ClientViewModel()
        {
            GetAllSharesCommand = new RelayCommand(ExecuteGetAllShares, CanExecuteGetAllShares);
            GetSharePerUserCommand = new RelayCommand(ExecuteGetSharePerUserCommand, CanExecuteGetSharePerUserCommand);

            handler = new HttpHandler();
            Shares = new ObservableCollection<Share>();
            GetUsers();
        }

        private async void GetUsers()
        {
            IDictionary<string, int> userNames2ID = await handler.GetAllUsersAsync("api/users");
            _userName2Id = new Dictionary<string, int>(userNames2ID);
        }

        private bool CanExecuteGetSharePerUserCommand()
        {
            return !String.IsNullOrEmpty(UserName);
        }

        private async void ExecuteGetSharePerUserCommand()
        {
            string temp = "api/shares" + "/" + _userName2Id[UserName];
            try
            {
                IEnumerable<Share> tempShares = await handler.GetSharePerUserAsync(temp);
                Shares.Clear();
                foreach (var item in tempShares)
                {
                    Shares.Add(item);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
        public bool CanExecuteGetAllShares()
        {
            return !String.IsNullOrEmpty(UserName);
        }
        public async void ExecuteGetAllShares()
        {
            try
            {
                IEnumerable<Share> tempShares = await handler.GetallSharesAsync("api/shares");
                Shares.Clear();
                foreach (var item in tempShares)
                {
                    Shares.Add(item);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**2.Common - project**

**Share.cs**

```
namespace Common
{
    public class Share
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public double Price { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**3.Server - WebApi project(yea I know what a great name)**

**WebApiConfig.cs**

```
namespace SharesApp
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

**Controllers folder**

**SharesController.cs**

```
namespace SharesApp.Controllers
{
    public class SharesController : ApiController
    {
        //this is a mock for a real database, i'm not sure where do I need to connect to the real DB        
        private static IDataBase _dataBase;
        public SharesController()
        {
            if (_dataBase == null)
            {
                _dataBase = new SharesDataBase();
            }
        }
        public IEnumerable<Share> GetAllShares()
        {
            try
            {
                return _dataBase.GetAllShares();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }
        }
        public IHttpActionResult GetUpdatedShares(int id)
        {
            IEnumerable<Share> share = null;
            try
            {
                share = _dataBase.GetShareById(id);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }
            if (share == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return Ok(share);
        }   
    }
```

**UsersController .cs**

```
namespace SharesApp.Controllers
{
    public class UsersController : ApiController
    {
        private Dictionary<string, int> _userName2Id;
        public UsersController()
        {
            _userName2Id = new Dictionary<string, int>();
            _userName2Id.Add("user10", 1);
            _userName2Id.Add("user20", 2);
        }
        public IDictionary<string, int> GetAllUserNames()
        {
            return _userName2Id;
        }
        public string GetUserNameById(int id)
        {
            if (!_userName2Id.ContainsValue(id))
            {
                return null;
            }
            return _userName2Id.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == id).Key;
        }
    }
}
```

**Models folder**

**IDataBase.cs**

```
namespace SharesApp.Models
{
    public interface IDataBase
    {
        IEnumerable<Share> GetAllShares();
        IEnumerable<Share> GetShareById(int id);

    }
}
```

**SharesDataBase.cs**

```
namespace SharesApp.Models
{
    public class SharesDataBase : IDataBase
    {
        //user name to list of shares names

        const string INTC = "INTC";
        const string MSFT = "MSFT";
        const string TEVA = "TEVA";
        const string YAHOO = "YAHOO";
        const string P500 = "P500";
        private List<Share> _shares;
        private Random _random;
        private int _maximum = 100;
        private int _minimum = 1;
        public Dictionary<int, List<string>> User2Shares { get; set; }

        private Object thisLock = new Object();  

        public SharesDataBase()
        {
            _random = new Random();
            User2Shares = new Dictionary<int, List<string>>();
            //init the shares list
            _shares = new List<Share>
        { 
            new Share { Id = 1, Name = INTC, Price = 1 }, 
            new Share { Id = 2, Name = MSFT, Price = 3.75 }, 
            new Share { Id = 3, Name = TEVA,  Price = 16.99},
            new Share { Id = 4, Name = YAHOO,  Price = 11.0},
            new Share { Id = 5, Name = P500,  Price = 5.55},
        };


            //init the users
            User2Shares.Add(1, new List<string>() { INTC, MSFT, TEVA });
            User2Shares.Add(2, new List<string>() { YAHOO, P500, TEVA });
            Task.Run(()=>UpdateShares());


        }
        private void UpdateShares()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);// wait for 1 sec
                lock (thisLock)
                {
                    foreach (var item in _shares)
                    {
                        int tempRandom = _random.Next(1, 1000);
                        if (tempRandom % 100 == 0)
                        {
                            item.Price = _random.NextDouble() * (_maximum - _minimum) + _minimum;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        public IEnumerable<Share> GetAllShares()
        {
            return _shares;
        }

        public IEnumerable<Share> GetShareById(int id)
        {
            if (!User2Shares.ContainsKey(id))
            {
                return null;
            }
            var listOfShares = User2Shares[id];
            if (listOfShares.Count == 0)
            {
                //this userName doesn't have any shares
                return null;
            }
            List<Share> sharesList = new List<Share>();
            foreach (var name in listOfShares)
            {
                var res = _shares.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == name);
                if (res != null)
                {
                    sharesList.Add(res);
                }

                //share is missing from the server
            }
            return sharesList;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This isn't an interview question, is it?

Comment: No. It is a task that a friend who works in the web domain which I have no knowledge of. Gave me as a practice to ramp up on web api and client server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### ClientViewModel

If you don't validate property setters, meaning you just store the setted value in a backing variable, you should use autoimplemented properties like so

```
public RelayCommand GetAllSharesCommand
{
    get; set;
}
```

which makes the code shorter and more readable.

---

You should only catch exceptions which you can/want to handle. If you have

> ```
> catch (Exception)
> {
>     throw;
> }
> ```

you can just ommit the `try..catch` because you will handle the exception at another place. Here the `try..catch` only adds noise to your code.

As an example, the `ExecuteGetAllShares()` method would look like so

```
public async void ExecuteGetAllShares()
{
    IEnumerable<Share> tempShares = await handler.GetallSharesAsync("api/shares");
    Shares.Clear();
    foreach (var item in tempShares)
    {
        Shares.Add(item);
    }
}
```

and would do the exact same thing.

Comment: I thought when accessing an external content you should always use try catch. but ok.

Comment: Using `try..catch` is good as long as you do something with the exception. Either logging it or handling it. Just `throwing` it is the same as omitting `try..catch`.

Comment: ok sure, this is what I meant to add logging, I had 4 hours so I didn't use Log4net or something like that, but I get your idea